# onCheckedChangedListener gets fired but does not save data to SharedPreferences (Android)

Tags: android

I have a settings page where the user can select the time for the countdown timer in my app. It has 3 radio buttons and what I want to happen is that when the user clicks on one of them, an int value gets saved to SharedPreferences as a "time" parameter for my timer in another activity.

The onCheckedChangedListener for the radio buttons gets fired but the values for time does not get saved to SharedPrefs.

Here is the snippet from my settings activity:

```
  @Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
    switch (buttonView.getId()) {
        case R.id.thirty:
            prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
            editor = prefs.edit();
            editor.putInt("time", 30000).apply();
            Toast.makeText(this, "h", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        case R.id.fifty:
            editor.putInt("time", 50000);
            editor.apply();
            break;
        case R.id.ninety:
            editor.putInt("time", 90000);
            editor.apply();
            break;
    }
}
```

And here is where I (unsuccessfully) retrieve the data in another activity:

```
    mprefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
    time = mprefs.getInt("time", 50000);

    cdTimer = new Timer(time, 1000);
```

Another thing is that when I set an onClickListener for the radio buttons like this, instead of onCheckedChanged everything works fine

```
    thirty = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.thirty);
    thirty.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(Options.this);
            editor = prefs.edit();
            editor.putInt("time", 30000).apply();
        }
    });
```

Can someone please explain why this is happening? I am very new to android programming so please be gentle in your explanations. Thank you.

Comment: Use intents to pass data between activities and dont forget to call commit() to save changes to preferences

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you need to add `if (isChecked)` to your `onCheckedChanged` function. Also initialization of prefs would like to go out of switch, so you function will look like this:

```
@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
    if (isChecked) {
        prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        switch (buttonView.getId()) {
            ....
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that other radiobutton's `onCheckedChanged` might overwrite value in preferences.

Comment: In my XML file I had this line android:checked="true". This was what caused my problem I think. It overwrote the value in the preferences. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Prefer to **call** `editor.commit();` **after your** `editor.putInt`

`commit()` writes the data **synchronously** (blocking the thread its called from). It then informs you about the success of the operation.

`apply()` schedules the data to be written **asynchronously**. It does not inform you about the success of the operation.

Answer (score 0):

You only initialise your editor in the first switch statement and not in the other two. If I were you I would initialise it outside of the click listener then it will be available to use everywhere.

```
        case R.id.thirty:
        prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putInt("time", 30000).apply();
        Toast.makeText(this, "h", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        break;
```

Comment: I initialized it in the first switch statement because I was testing that radio button. I did initialize it outside but the same thing happends